# Arrayplotter ( Problem with graph, Y values does not show )

Tags: c++, visual-studio, graph

By using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, arrayplotter extension does not show the y values:

[image]

The code of the graph (C++) :

```
int main() {
    const int size = 5; // You can change the size of the array if needed
    int xValues[size] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    int yValues[size];

    // Calculate y = x^2 for each x
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        yValues[i] = xValues[i] * xValues[i];
    }

    // Print the values of x and y
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << "x = " << xValues[i] << ", y = " << yValues[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to solve the problems (make the graph look complete with values) ?

Comment: Why did you tag `arraylist`?  Second, the issue has to do with whatever arrayplotter is, and has nothing to do with the [C++ code](https://godbolt.org/z/qheM9qKvK).  The values are not "lost" or wrong when running a C++ program.  Maybe find a tag that actually deals with arrayplotter (which I have no idea what that is), so that someone actually sees this question and knows what the solution is.